# Java class and method inside other class question

Tags: java

I have very simple theoretical question. I simplified code that I have. What is the last code construcion "Www". In my code Www is another class. And here in Qqq I have this Www run(). This is method connected to another class or what? I cannot get it.

```
public class Qqq {
    //class fields

    public Qqq (int x) {
        //constructor
    }

    public boolean doSomething(int y){

        return false;

        //this is method
    }

    public Www run(){
        if (!isRun) {
            isRun = true;
            return new Www();
        }
        return null;

        // What is this???
    }
}
```

Comment: Method `run()` returns an object of type `Www`, which is a class.

Comment: as with any method declaration `public Www run(){` - `public` is a method modifier (public access); `Www` is the return type (similar to `boolean` in previous method); `run` is the method name; and `()` is the parameter list (in this case none)

Comment: You can find lots of good tutorials here: https://dev.java/learn/ - for example, learn about [classes, objects and methods](https://dev.java/learn/classes-and-objects/)